# What is the position on capitalising martial art styles?

Tags: discussion

As someone who occasionally looks to edit questions and answers, I'd like to know if there is a community consensus on whether to capitalise the name of a martial art, or not?

For example:

> I have studied Goju-ryu for 10 years and....

or

> I have studied goju-ryu for 10 years and ...

On sites such as Wikipedia, capitalisation appears to be consistently applied: [Goju-Ryu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C5%8Dj%C5%AB-ry%C5%AB) **- what is the rule here?**

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any community guideline for capitalization. Everyone basically writes as they wish, and the community has not made an effort yet to apply any writing style guidelines.

Comment: Would you say there's any need for a rule to be created? Even if the rule was, there is no rule? I only ask as other SE sites are quite hot on spelling and grammar.

Comment: @Longshanks No, I do not believe a rule is needed. I think this is only really an issue when people start disagreeing, and most of the editing issues now are more basic: there are no sentences, or posts are unintelligible. If you plan on editing lots of posts, we can discuss details, but if this is just an occasional event, I would just use what you think appropriate.